# Accessing members of struct from queue of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I am having an issue trying to assign a value to a member variable of my struct, PCB. I am using a queue of pointers to my struct. So I first dereference the pointer passed to the `inititiate_process` function, and next try to deference the pointer from the `ready_queue` to access the member variable. How do I access this member variable? I am getting an 'invalid type conversion' on this line of code `(static_cast<PCB*>(ready_queue->front()))->next_pcb_ptr = &pcb;`.

Here is my struct in a header file

```
#ifndef PCB_H
#define PCB_H

struct PCB {
    int p_id;
    int *page_table_ptr;
    int page_table_size;
    int *next_pcb_ptr;
};
#endif // !PCB_H
```

Here is my source cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include "PCB.h"

using namespace std;

void initiate_process(queue<int*>* ready_queue) {
    // allocate dynamic memory for the PCB
    PCB* pcb = new PCB;

    // assign pcb next
        if(!(ready_queue->empty())){
            // get prior pcb and set its next pointer to current
            (static_cast<PCB*>(ready_queue->front()))->next_pcb_ptr = &pcb;
        }
}

void main(){
    queue<int *> ready_queue;
    initiate_process(&ready_queue);
}
```

Comment: consider using an `std::unique_ptr<T>` instead of `T*`

Comment: Save yourself a bit of trouble by passing a reference rather than a pointer. `void initiate_process(queue<int*>* ready_queue)` -> `void initiate_process(queue<int*>& ready_queue)`

Comment: Why not store pointers to `PCB`s in the queue? You seem to be going out of your way to make this hard on yourself.

Comment: Anyway, no matter what casting you did at the beginning, `next_pcb_ptr` is still an `int *` and `&pcb` is a `PCB**`. I think the solution to this is stop and rethink what you are doing.

Comment: In addition to switching to `PCB*` over `int*` already brought up by others, you should consider that `if (!(ready_queue->empty())) {` will never enter, unless you put something in the queue first, which you don't seem to be doing anywhere.

Comment: @KillzoneKid I am inserting to the queue after the if statement, but didn't include it. That if statement is not pertinent to the issue anyways, I will remove it.

Comment: `I am now accessing correctly, but not assigning correctly` Change `int *next_pcb_ptr;` to `PCB *next_pcb_ptr;` and `ready_queue.front()->next_pcb_ptr = &pcb;` to `ready_queue.front()->next_pcb_ptr = pcb;`

Comment: Thank you @KillzoneKid and user4581301, that solves the issue. I had not correctly understood pointers and was not implementing them correctly. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to show the correct solution, since if you do this, the answers no longer make sense.  I've backed up some of your edits.  If you feel the need to put comments or updates in the question, please at least put them after the old text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you need the static_cast? I suggest in your PCB.h you should instead use

```
struct PCB *next_pcb_ptr;
```

and then in the main part of the program and initiate_process, use struct PCB * instead of int *

```
void initiate_process(queue<struct PCB *> *ready_queue) {

  // allocate dynamic memory for the PCB
  struct PCB *pcb = new struct PCB;

  // assign pcb next
  if(!(ready_queue->empty())){

    (ready_queue->front())->next_pcb_ptr = pcb;

  }

}
```